# How Do I Create a Colored Border on a PictureBox Control?

Tags: c#

I have an PictureBox and an Image in `PictureBox1.Image` property.
How do I place a border around the Image?

Comment: Do you understand what it is you're asking to do?

Answer (score 12):

This has always been what I use for that:

To change the border color, call this from the Paint event handler of your Picturebox control:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
```

To change the border color dynamically, for instance from a mouseclick event, I use the Tag property of the picturebox to store the color and adjust the Click event of the picturebox to retrieve it from there. For example:

```
if (pictureBox1.Tag == null) { pictureBox1.Tag = Color.Red; } //Sets a default color
  ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle, (Color)pictureBox1.Tag, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

The picturebox Click event, then, would go something like this:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Color)pictureBox1.Tag == Color.Red) { pictureBox1.Tag = Color.Blue; }
            else {pictureBox1.Tag = Color.Red; }
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
```

You'll need `using System.Drawing;` at the beginning and don't forget to call `pictureBox1.Refresh()` at the end. Enjoy!

Comment: Glad my [original suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446478/how-do-i-create-a-colored-border-on-a-picturebox-control/13361940#comment18241047_13361940) was helpful (3 years earlier).

Answer (score 10):

You can't set the size and color of the border of a `PictureBox`.
But you can do a little trick to accomplish that.

Set your image to the `BackgroundImage` property.
Set the `BackgroundImageLayout` to `Center`.
Change the `BackColor` property to the color you want the border to be.
Now resize the `PictureBox` enough to show the back color, which will now visually act like a border.

You can also use the `Padding` property to accomplish the last step.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This method has some draw backs tried to use it without success in a complex layout, found overriding `OnPaint()` method of the `PictureBox` worked best.

Comment: This also has trouble when using transparent images.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own PictureBox by inheriting from `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox` and overriding the `PictureBox` class `OnPaint` method, from here use the `System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint` class to paint your custom border using the 'DrawBorder' method and pass in your 'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs' from the 'OnPaint' method.

Something like this;

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

public class CustomPictureBox : PictureBox
{
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) 
  {
    base.OnPaint(e);
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
  }
}
```

This is just a  quick example (untested) to get you started, sorry I can't be more thorough.

Comment: If it's a one off you can always just call `ControlPaint.DrawBorder` from your PictureBox controls `Paint` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I was here because I was facing the same problem. I pointed out a simpler solution and that is.

1. Place a `label` behind a `picturebox`.
2. Change the back color of the `label` to the color of the wanted border.
3. Set `label`'s `AutoSize` property to `false` and Resize the `label` as you want.

Sample:

[image]

Comment: even we can set panel and other controls as well instead just a label

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this goals, I used a button with background imagem and set FlatApparence property