# I want to have a border highlight animation on my app

Tags: c#, loops, animation, uwp, border

I want after the button i clicked that there comes a animation and lands on the picture that is the number of the _random but i cant find anything on the google

ive tried to google and ask around but still havent got what i want

```
public sealed partial class FilePage : Page
    {
        DataPage value = new DataPage();
        Random _random = new Random();
        private int time = 0;
        DispatcherTimer Timer;

        public FilePage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

 //////////
 //////////cut some off to keep this short (turning the border black again)
 //////////


            Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
            Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            Timer.Start();
        }

        public void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            int value = _random.Next(1, 13);
            ((Grid)gMainGrid.FindName($"g{value}")).BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            Timer.Stop();
            SpinnerSecond.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            DataWatch.valueWatch = value;
            RollKnop.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;



        }
    }
}
```

so i want to have a animation that goes over the borders like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/images/fluent/traveling-focus-fullscreen-light-rf.gif for like the 3 seconds and then land on the right one, im sorry if i sound like a demander but im already googling for 2 days

Comment: 13 images, 1 button on window

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that you have to use ControlPaint.DrawBorder if the pictures are in pictureboxes, you draw for one picture, after a short delay you remove it, then draw it on the other, etc
After 3 secondes, you keep that going until it lands on the good picture then you stop everything

EDIT : You might want to check that if that hasn't been already done : [How Do I Create a Colored Border on a PictureBox Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446478/how-do-i-create-a-colored-border-on-a-picturebox-control)

Comment: My pictures are in grids:
 <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="g1">
            <Image Margin="20" Source="/Assets/1.png" />
          
        </Grid>

Do i need to change that?
sorry not the best programmer .

Comment: Well, I'm not a pro in WPF apps, but I found that, it may help you : <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769291/how-do-i-put-a-border-on-my-grid-in-wpf>

Answer (score 0):

To short, you can create a loop that traverses the elements inside the container and sets the `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` for them.

This is a simple code example:

**ColorBorderPage.xaml**

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <controls:WrapPanel x:Name="ItemsContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="160" Height="120" Margin="0,50">
        <StackPanel Background="Gray" Width="100" Height="50" Margin="0,0,10,10"/>
        <StackPanel Background="Gray" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        <StackPanel Background="Gray" Width="160" Height="50"/>
    </controls:WrapPanel>
    <Button Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I created a Panel called `ItemsContainer`, which replaces the image with a `StackPanel` and add a button to trigger the animation.

**ColorBorderPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int count = ItemsContainer.Children.Count;
    int index = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var item = ItemsContainer.Children[index] as StackPanel;
        item.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
        item.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        item.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        index = index == count - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
    }
}
```

In the code, by first getting the number of child elements in the container, then setting the `Border` one by one through the while loop, and restarting when looping to the end.

According to your animation requirements, you can use `Task.Delay()`, which will delay the specified time before proceeding to the next step.

---

This is just an example, but it should be able to meet your needs, you just need to replace the `StackPanel` with an `Image`.

Best regards.